# Patch tool on huge files

Tags: linux, embedded, diff, patch, embedded-linux

I'm the new proud owner of 10 rasberry pie, all running the same OS and same tools.

I'm looking for an easy way to update them all once.

The OS is almost 4GB, and is very slow to copy one by one.

I found two tools bsdiff/bspatch, but it use a lot of memory, too much to be usable in my case.

So I'm looking for an other tool like this one... I don't want to have the smallest patch possible.

I just want to avoid copying 2Go of zero each time.

I can't use aptitude or git because I need to do to much modification each time.

The perfect solution would run like this :

wget http://myserver.com/mynewimg | patcher /dev/sda

Does anyone have an idea ?

Good week end every body

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rsync`. It has build-in algorithms to update only changed regions of a file.

Comment: I can't let my rasberry connected all time

Comment: you can run `rsync` from your rasberry